# My Bukkit Timer runs once and when i do the command again it, its faster

Tags: timer, bukkit

My Bukkit plugin does a timer that puts on armor, counts down and then removes armor then when i run it again the timer is faster? Why is this? I want users to be able todo the command multiple times without having to login again. Can someone help me?

```
    if(args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("BlackWing") )
        {
            final ItemStack[] oldarmor1;
            oldarmor1 = p.getInventory().getArmorContents();
            ItemStack ib = new ItemStack(Material.CHAINMAIL_BOOTS, 1);
            ib.addEnchantment(Enchantment.PROTECTION_FALL, 4);
            ib.addEnchantment(Enchantment.PROTECTION_ENVIRONMENTAL, 1);
            ItemStack il=new ItemStack(Material.CHAINMAIL_LEGGINGS, 1);
            il.addEnchantment(Enchantment.PROTECTION_ENVIRONMENTAL, 1);
            ItemStack ic = new ItemStack(Material.CHAINMAIL_CHESTPLATE, 1);
            ic.addEnchantment(Enchantment.PROTECTION_ENVIRONMENTAL, 1);
            ItemStack ih = new ItemStack(Material.CHAINMAIL_HELMET, 1);
            ih.addEnchantment(Enchantment.PROTECTION_ENVIRONMENTAL, 1);
            ItemStack[] armors1 = { ib , 
              il, 
              ic, 
               ih};
            p.getInventory().setArmorContents(armors1);
            PotionEffect pe = new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.JUMP, 600, 5);
            p.addPotionEffect(pe);
            ItemStack ironsword = new ItemStack(Material.IRON_SWORD,1);
            ironsword.addEnchantment(Enchantment.DAMAGE_ALL, 3);
            p.getInventory().setItem( 0,  ironsword);
            getServer().getScheduler().scheduleAsyncRepeatingTask(this, new Runnable(){

                public void run(){

                    if (number != 0){

                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "[FairyTail] " + ChatColor.GRAY + number + " seconds left");
                        number=number -1;
                    }else{
                        p.getInventory().setArmorContents(oldarmor1);



                    }
                    }


            }, 0L, 20L);

        }
        number=30;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code snippet you provided, the scheduled task that counts down is never cancelled. The second time the command is executed by the same player, there will actually be two tasks running in the background, both decrementing `number` (amount of seconds) and therefore causing the countdown to be twice as fast. To fix this you could make sure that once the task is done counting down the seconds it gets cancelled. Writing a new class that extends `BukkitRunnable` might be really helpful in this case because these can cancel themselves (for example in the case when the 30 seconds are over).

Comment: So what would i do to cancel it?

Comment: You can either use the cancelTask(id) method in the `BukkitScheduler` class or write your own class that extends `BukkitRunnable` and then use this.cancel(). The ID of the task is returned as an int when you schedule the task: `int id = getServer().getScheduler().scheduleSync... `